# While loop not working

Tags: iphone, loops

So i have put a while loop in the viewDidLoad method of a viewController, but when i load the view controller it doesn't work and gives me a SIGTERM. Here's the code of the while loop.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
while (appDelegate.gobletCheckInt == 0 || appDelegate.gobletCheckInt == 1) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mainSprite.frame, getGobletImg.frame)) {
        haveGobletImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold Goblet.png"];
    }
}

appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
getGobletImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold Goblet.png"];
```

}

Those last two lines don't matter much. So should i not put this in the viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1):

The appDelegate object is filled out after you try to use it. It looks like you need to move the assignment of appDelegate to be above the while loop.

Comment: Could you post a portion of the stack trace? Which line does the debugger stop at when the app terminates? What are the values of your member variables? I don't see how what you have above could work without moving the appDelegate assignment above the while loop, but you may need more than that. It's hard to say without seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be getting killed by the runtime for having an infinite loop? Where do you set gobletCheckInt to something other than 0 or 1? Maybe you should:

```
NSLog(@"%d", appDelegate.gobletCheckInt);
```

Inside your while loop.

Now I have to do the obligatory tsk-tsk that this is really bad architecture. :) You shouldn't be checking properties on your application delegate from your view controller. The application delegate is strictly for receiving messages from UIApplication, like when the app launches or terminates. It shouldn't be used for holding state in properties.

Comment: That's what i want is an infinite loop. gobletCheckInt is never equal to anything but 1 or 0. Maybe i don't even want a loop. What i really want is for that code in the loop to keep on executing.

Comment: You should execute it on a timer, then. Basically going into an infinite loop will get you killed by the runtime, since your program will become unresponsive. Read the docs on NSTimer. If you want to go deeper, you can schedule stuff on the program's run loop, but that's a bit more advanced. (I have done this for things like Reachability testing)